# Creating a bracket tree from XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a tree for a bracket from an XML file.

A match in the bracket consists of four teams. The winner of that team advances to the next round.

If a match consists of 3 teams and a child match, then the child match determines the fourth team for the parent match.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Round>
    <Match>
      <Team id="A1">Apples</Team>
      <Team id="B2">Banannas</Team>
      <Team id="C3">Cantalopes</Team>
      <Team id="D4">Durians</Team>
    </Match>
    <Match>
      <Team id="A2">Avocados</Team>
      <Team id="B2">Blueberry</Team>
      <Team id="C3">Coconut</Team>
      <Team id="TBD">
        <Match>
          <Team id="A3">Apricots</Team>
          <Team id="B5">Banannas</Team>
          <Team id="C9">Cantalopes</Team>
          <Team id="D6">Durians</Team>
        </Match>
      </Team>
    </Match>
  </Round>
```

Here is my function to create the tree:

```
   private void CreateTree(XmlTextReader reader, Node<Match<Team>> parent,  Match<Team> currentMatch)
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case "Match": //We need to make a new match!
                        currentMatch = new Match<Team>();
                        Node<Match<Team>> child = new Node<Match<Team>>(currentMatch);
                        parent.Add(currentMatch);
                        CreateTree(reader, child, currentMatch);
                        break;
                    case "Team": //We need to add a team!
                        string id = reader.GetAttribute("id");
                        if (id != "TBD")
                        {
                            string name = reader.Value;
                            currentMatch.Add(new Team(id, name));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentMatch.Add(Team.Tbd);
                        }
                        CreateTree(reader, parent, currentMatch);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
              CreateTree(reader, parent.Parent, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

I initially call this function in the following way:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", fileName);
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path);
CreateTree(reader, tree, null);
reader.Close();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, my tree is empty, and I'm having trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong. Any help figuring this out would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The XML itself is a tree. So `XElement.Load` will give you a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node node = new Node(FILENAME);
            node.Print(node, 1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Team
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public Node child = null;
        public List<List<Team>> matches = new List<List<Team>>();

        public Node()
        {
        }
        public Node(string filename)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create(filename);
            CreateTree(reader, this, false);
        }
        private void CreateTree(XmlReader reader, Node parent, Boolean isChild)
        {
            Boolean endElement = false;
            while (!reader.EOF && !endElement)
            {
                if (!isChild)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                }
                isChild = false;

                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            switch (reader.Name)
                            {
                                case "Match": //We need to make a new match
                                    List<Team> match = new List<Team>();
                                    parent.matches.Add(match);
                                    CreateTree(reader, parent, false);
                                    break;
                                case "Team": //We need to add a team!
                                    parent.matches.Last().Add(new Team() { 
                                        id = reader.GetAttribute("id"), 
                                        name = reader.ReadString().Trim()
                                    });
                                    if (reader.Name == "Match")
                                    {
                                        parent.child = new Node();
                                        CreateTree(reader, parent.child, true);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            //break out of while loop
                            endElement = true;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void Print(Node node, int level)
        {
            foreach (List<Team> match in node.matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Match", new string(' ',5 * level));
                foreach (Team team in match)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Team : Name = '{1}', Id = '{2}'", new string(' ', (5 * level) + 3), team.name, team.id);
                }
            }
            if (node.child != null)
            {
                Print(node.child, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work. Is there a way to print it to verify it is working?

Comment: I made some improvements and added a print method().